# Zipkin export flag is not getting printed in the Spring Boot Application logs

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

`I am implementing sleuth and zipkin locally and getting the following issue:

zipkin export flag of sleuth is not getting printed at all in the service logs. Only application name, trace id and span id is coming as shown bellow:

```
INFO [sleuthpoc,a3b11678e089f17b,a3b11678e089f17b]
```

My bootstrap.properties is:

```
spring.zipkin.base-url=(http://localhost:9411/)
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1
```

Spring Cloud version: 2021.0.4
Spring Boot version: 2.7.5
Java version: 17

Is there is any property that I am missing here as I am not able to see the service trace in the zipkin server because information is not sent to zipkin because of this issue.

Trying locally and expecting to see the zipkin export flag in logs and service request trace in zipkin server`

Comment: Maybe you also need to set `spring.zipkin.sender.type = web` and `spring.zipkin.service.name = your_app_name`?

Comment: It's didn't worked with the mentioned solution also. I already tried it. 

My A service controller is calling the B service controller and I can't see the trace in Zipkin server at all.

Comment: I don't have another idea, so I would start with checking whether it is really a client side issue (if you didn't do that already), that is whether your app has required beans registered, most of all: `zipkinSender`, and whether zipkinSender is trying to send anything to the Zipkin server.

Comment: I have the basic implementation implemented from spring.io article and it seems that ZipkinSender bean is not discussed anywhere in any article available over the net. Let me explore on ZipkinSender also and see if it helps.
I have posted another question on stackoverflow and not yet have received any answer on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74402754/zipkin-server-is-not-showing-microservices-trace

Comment: `zipkinSender` bean is autoregistered by spring-cloud-sleuth-autoconfigure based on your configuration (configuration and classes available at runtime). You could check whether `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-autoconfigure` is added to your project (I think it is transitively added if you use `spring-cloud-starter-zipkin`) and then whether `zipkinSender` is registered in your application context when your service has started - for me this would be the first step to be sure that service is actually trying to send spans to Zipkin server.

Comment: For servlet applications `zipkinSender` is of RestTemplateSender type, for reactive applications this would be WebClientSender.

Comment: Nothing works here for the issue. I am not able to see the traces in the ZipkinServer.

Comment: Well, we know that already :) The issue might be on both sides, but its more probable that it is client side issue, so I suggested that you check beans in your client service. If bean `zipkinSender` is there, then the next step is find out whether it actually tries to send anything.

Comment: I checked that @akoz and found that traceIDs are going to Zipkin. Can see them in Zipkin server. However, traces are not there and found nothing around it over the net. Trying to now further digging to know what is going along with TraceIDs to Zipkin server. Will keep you posted for sure. Thanks a lot for your active participation in this issue

Comment: The issue was in the way RestTemplate used in the implementation. TraceID is stopped printing in the logs as told by Marcin in his answer. The reason that it was not going to Zipkin was due to RestTemplate issue. RestTemplate object was created by new keyword which is not recommended. It has to be injected as a Bean in the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIR We've stopped printing it starting with Spring Cloud 2021.0.0. It's not being put to MDC anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just to confirm, I am not able to see the trace of the services calls in the Zipkin server. Is this is because of this reason?

Comment: No, that's not because of that. Maybe you're not sampling 100% of requests? Remember about setting the sampler probability property

Comment: I have setup the sampler probability property as:
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1

Still the same issue.

Comment: It will be difficult to help you without a sample. You can check spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples for reference